# C# Equivalent of python3 int.to_bytes

Tags: c#

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so is there an equivalent of the `int.to_bytes(int,"big")` from python3 in C# ?

This is what i would do manually i guess.

```
private byte[] IntToBytesBig(int number, int len)
        {
            byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)                //if little endian, reverse to get big endian
                Array.Reverse(bytes);
            if (bytes.Length == len) return bytes;          //if already desired length, return.
            if (bytes.Length > len)                         //if length is too long, remove some elements
            {
                var bytesTmp = Array.Empty<byte>();
                bytes.CopyTo(bytesTmp, bytes.Length - len);
                bytes = bytesTmp;
            }
            else                                            //if length is too small, add 0's in byte
            {
                Array.Reverse(bytes);
                for (var i = bytes.Length; i < len; i++)
                    bytes[i] =(byte) 0;
                Array.Reverse(bytes);
            }
            return bytes;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [BinaryPrimitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly, I really don't get how to achieve my goal :/

Comment: Try something like `var arr = new byte[4];` followed by `BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32BigEndian(arr, 123);`